# a element not showing background image

Tags: css, html

I am trying to add a backgroung image for a "a" element, but it would only show part of the image ( so if I have Home as value, whatever space home takes that is what is shows of the image, if the value is empty it wont show anything of the image).

Despite I have setted up the width and height of the "a" element to display.

Can anybody help me?

Code.

```
<div style="width:1200px;height:25px;text-align:left;">
<a href="#" style="background-image:url('Images2/Heading/TopMenu.gif');width:176px;height:25px;margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;">&#160;</a>
<a href="#" style="background-image:url('Images2/Heading/TopMenu.gif');width:176px;height:25px;margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;">&#160;</a>
<a href="#" style="background-image:url('Images2/Heading/TopMenu.gif');width:176px;height:25px;margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;">&#160;</a>
<a href="#" style="background-image:url('Images2/Heading/TopMenu.gif');width:176px;height:25px;margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;">&#160;</a>
<a href="#" style="background-image:url('Images2/Heading/TopMenu.gif');width:176px;height:25px;margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;">&#160;</a>
</div>
```

I am sure is something silly, but I cant find out what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<a>` is an inline element. Inline elements cannot have a set width and height.

You therefore need to change the display mode of the element using the CSS property `display`.

Use `display: block;` if you want your elements to be taken out of the flow of text and considered a block (ie.: stacked vertically, one block per line).

Use `display: inline-block;` if you want your element to behave like an inline element position wise but have block-like properties.

**Note:** `inline-block` is supported by IE6 on `<a>`. In IE6, `inline-block` display style is only supported on elements which has an `inline` default style.

Comment: According to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html - inline-block is not a solid option.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: According to the same link you posted: *IE 6/7 accepts the value only on elements with a natural `display: inline`.* An anchor has a natural `display: inline` therefore it is solid on that element. I even stated as such in my post.

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, that's correct, but what do you plan on doing for FF2 users?

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: Firefox 2 is used by < 1% of the web users today. Do we still support IE4 and IE5 on the basis that < 1% are using them? You are being very selective on your argument.

Comment: @Andrew: Not at all. Using block/float takes care of everybody all the way back to IE5.5. Using inline-block excludes FF2 users.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: Then its a choice. I can understand people not upgrading IE due to enterprise restrictions. I cannot understand people not upgrading Firefox. At that point, people are making a conscious choice to be left behind. I will never support < 5% market share if it means I sacrifice maintainability.

Comment: With all due respect, Andrew, I don't see how using the widely-accepted method of block'n'float "sacrifices maintainability." The difference between our two method is pretty small, so I don't mind splitting paths here out of respect for you and the great contributions you've made here.

Answer (score 4):

Add `display:block;` to the anchors ([`block` vs `inline-block`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)). Once you do that though, you may need to `float:left;` the anchors to keep them side-by-side. If you go that route, follow them all up with a `clear:both;` div.

```
a.box  { float:left; width:100px; height:25px; margin:0 8px; }
.clear { clear:both; }
```

```
<a href="#" class="box">Foo</a> 
<a href="#" class="box">Foo</a> 
<a href="#" class="box">Foo</a> 
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: -1: Use `inline-block`, which IE6 understands perfectly on inline elements instead of using floats.

Comment: You're downvoting based on that alone?

Comment: Yes, but on second thought that might be a bit harsh, vote removed.

Comment: @Andrew: `inline-block` doesn't seem to work for FF2 according to quirksmode.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: Firefox 2 is used by < 1% of the web users today. Do we still support IE4 and IE5 on the basis that < 1% are using them? You are being very selective on your argument.

Comment: @Andrew: Not at all. Using block/float takes care of everybody all the way back to IE5.5. Using inline-block excludes FF2 users.